# Pade Approximant on Mathematica

Tags: pade-approximation

I would like to know how to code Pade Approximation on Mathematica.

And also I have solved Eigen values and have 20 coefficient values,but I am not sure how to code on mathematica.Can you please explain me how to code and get values using Pade Approximanyt.

Thanks,

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PadeApproximation.html

Comment: Thanks,I have checked this.please see my below coding and there is no output.                                                                                                          f[x_] := [1 - 3/4*x^2 - 21/16*x^3 - 333/64*x^4 - 30885/1024*x^5]
enot = {1, -(3/4), -(21/16), -(333/64), -(30885/1024), -(916731/
    4096), -(65518401/32768), -(2723294673/131072), -(1030495099053/
    4194304), -(54626982511455/16777216), -(6417007431590595/
    134217728)};
PadeApproximant[[x, enot], {x, 0, {5, 5}}]

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have found 20 perturbation terms for ground state,now I need to do pade approximation for ground state..I stuck with coding part,as I dont understand how to invoke a function.